# Fetching only ids of features with QgsFeatureRequest in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, features, unique-id, qgsfeaturerequest

Using a `QgsFeatureRequest` by default will fetch all attributes (including geometry) of the features. I can use `.setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)` to not fetch the geometry, and `.setSubsetOfAttributes(['value'], vector_layer.fields())` to fetch only one attribute.

I am using `QgsFeatureRequest` because I need the filter `setDistanceWithin(QgsGeometry, tolerance)`.

I would like to fetch no attributes to optimise my query as I only need the id of the features.

Comment: Can you please explain your problem/question more in details? Because @BERA's solution, I assumed, is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRequest.html#a85f831f339a9882822d5d5cf19b29fdf indicates that "An empty attributes list indicates that no attributes will be fetched".

That means by combining `.setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)` and `.setSubsetOfAttributes([])` you should receive Features that are little more than their IDs.

Comment: I had somehow missed that in the api, this is what i was looking for and probably can't be improved on as it is a hint for the data provider and so is optimised at this level, except if there are more costly data than just attributes and geometry.